# Install Magento 2.3 local gives a error 500

Tags: magento2, http-error-500

I try to install Magento 2.3 local in windows but i get error 500. What can i do to solve this problem or/and where is the problem settled? Thanks for advising. I am a absolute beginner.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check your Xampp control panel Apache and MySql is Start action and check with phpinfo file

Comment: You mean this is all started? I will attach picture.

Comment: Check the apache error log. Should be in xampp\apache\logs\error.log

Comment: How can i add picture here?

Comment: Please edit your question add picture you need to add

Comment: Thanks, do you see new picture, that is appache file, which screenshots you need more to help me?

Comment: you are run all command ???

Comment: What you mean with run all command?

Comment: `php bin/magento s:s:d -f , php bin/magento setup:di:compile, php bin/magento s:up,php bin/magento c:c,php bin/magento c:f , And remove the all pub/static and view_preprocessed` in command line

Comment: Sorry Mohit, you are expert i am a absolute beginner. In which file or which program can i check these? In windows 10? Can you tell me exactly where to go?

Comment: you are connect with me skype i will explain full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first solution :-

I think run all command

```
php bin/magento s:s:d -f

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento c:c

php bin/magento c:f
```

And remove the all `pub/static and view_preprocessed`

Second solution :-

open this file your go to this path `xampp\apache\conf` xampp sever and `httpd.conf`.

Find the `LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version` and remove the # . And this module is enable.

After check your magento.

Hope this help your

Thanks ...