# Magento 2 fresh install, admin panel UI issue

Tags: magento2.3

I am new to Mangento. I just finished setting up Magento. Home page works fine however when I login to admin panel, it does not look good. Please check these screenshots. How can I fix this? Notice that the main body in all section is not displaying properly.
Here are acreenshots https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6XbS.jpg
[image]

Comment: you run all command ??? and check this link how to run all command --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/312463/85907

Comment: yes, did not help.

Comment: you check console error

Comment: everything got messed up because I tried this "And remove the all pub/static and view_preprocessed", now there is permission error everywhere

Comment: you download magento 2 and again install

Comment: @mothit-patel thank you, that is the only option now. But thanks for your efforts.

Comment: welcome @burgur...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. The problem has nothing to do with Magento.

It was a problem caused by advance configuration in Firefox. The config option "browser.display.use_document_fonts" which was set to 0, changing it to 1 in "about:config" in Firefox fixed the problem.